# Expression for polygons that intersect with others in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover and I want to create a rule for styling a polygon layer, building an expression that aply to those polygons that intersect a polygon from another layer. This is what I wrote, but it doesn't work

```
intersects($geometry, geometry(get_feature_by_id("my_layer", 1)))
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use single quotes to reference the layer: `'` instead of `"`:

```
intersects($geometry, geometry(get_feature_by_id('my_layer', 1)))
```

If you want to test against the whole layer, you can use [`aggregate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate):

```
intersects($geometry, aggregate('my_layer', 'collect', $geometry))
```

---

[Since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core) you can also use [`overlay_intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects):

**To test only against feature 1**

```
overlay_intersects('my_layer', filter:=$id=1)
```

**To test against the whole layer**

```
overlay_intersects('my_layer')
```